# How to get words from sentence to be stored in separate string in command prompt in java

Tags: java, android, variables, integer

I need to store users input from command prompt, 
for eg, if user types "hello 23"

I need to check "hello" and to get 23 to be stored in separate Integer

Comment: do you mean to split the string?

Comment: is your app shell-based?

Comment: @Apostolos.. no, its an input from user in command prompt, and i want to get the second word (Variable)

Comment: yes ok we are taking about the same thing. get the input from user and split the string. other members have already answered. string the string and take the second element of the array :)

Comment: @Apostolos : Kindly edit the comment. "string the string" does not make any sense .

Comment: so , anyone know how can be done?

Comment: sorry i cannot find how to edit my comment. i meant "split the string"

Answer (score 1):

Considering user's input as one string you should split it by whitespace and then parse the second element.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);  
String userInput;
userInput = in.nextLine();
String[] arrayOfStrings = userInput.split("\\s+");
Integer number = Integer.parseInt(arrayOfStrings[1]);
```

Comment: You need to specify more requirements and tell what is wrong with your code. Saying "it's not working" is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

[Console.readline()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Console.html#readLine%28%29)

[String.split("\s+")](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

[Integer.parseInt()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29)